# how to view multiple juju environment on juju-gui

Tags: juju

i've added 2 environment on juju called them en01 and en02 of type MaaS, is there a way to view/select them on juju-gui to manage the services deployed?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported in the juju-gui, you will need to deploy a new instance of the juju-gui for each environment. The juju-gui is designed to be deployed on the bootstrap node without issue so you don't need new machines for the GUI.

Comment: hi hatch, but to view the second environment with its services deployed on machines, how do i've to make to open a second istance in juju-gui? i've tryied to make the login using the password found in .jenv but nothing. In the default environment (en01) juju-gui works with second one (en02) no! thanks

Comment: You need to deploy the juju-gui to the second environment as well. You can't deploy two instances to the same environment and have it access the other.

Comment: ok perfect, so i've to create 2 juju environment and for each one have a node dedicated a juju-gui.